# Getting faster results from 2 databases to form 1 resultset

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

So here is my scenario...

[image]

The bug_tracker table is in one server and task_traker is in another.

I want to show a combined result but can't since there are in two separate databases remotely.

So I am calling the task tracker first and then getting the bug details per iteration.

```
$task = oci_parse($task_conn, "select * from task_table where ....");
oci_execute($task);  
while ($task_row = oci_fetch_array($task, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    $bug = oci_parse($bug_conn, "select * from bug_table where id = " . $task_row['BUGID'] );
    oci_execute($bug);  
    while ($task_row = oci_fetch_array($task, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        ... //output
    }
    ... //output
}
```

But this entire process is making it very slow... since there are large number of records and columns.

Is there any way to make it **even slightly faster**? Note: I don't have access so can't setup oracle db links.

Comment: I haven't worked with Oracle much, but it looks like you could get all the BUGIDs from your first query and then use `IN()` instead of `=` so you would only have to execute the second query once instead of repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve it using the IN statement:

```
<?php
    $task = oci_parse($task_conn, "select * from task_table where  ....");
    oci_execute($task);  

    while ($task_row = oci_fetch_array($task, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        $bugs[] = $task_row['BUGID'];
        $users[] = $task_row['USER'];
        $status[] = $task_row['TASK_STATUS']; 
    }

    $bug = oci_parse($bug_conn, "select * from bug_table where id IN (" . implode(',', $bugs) . ");" );
    oci_execute($bug);  

    while ($task_row = oci_fetch_array($task, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        // ...
    }
```

?>

On a sidenote, why are you not using PDO? I believe using it will already give you a performance boost.

Comment: 1. Here ID is not the only requirement I need the data as well. How can I store that in an local array and access it.
2. Its not possible... both tables are in different databases in different servers. there are 2 different connections.

Comment: I've just edited the first while loop, now you'll have three arrays holding the data from the task table. Just add more arrays if you have any other fields.

Comment: So here is the problem while displaying all the rows.... how to show status and users along side during the iteration of task_row. Hope you understand...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... but if you want to keep the user and status synchronized, maybe you could use the "user" as the array keys?

Comment: In simple words how to generate for eg: the first row of my requirement... from the 2nd iteration which is the task connection.... i get the columns... but how to get the related title and status which I have collected for that particular bugid... can you show an example. Since we are storing the data in individual arrays

Comment: I tried and its much faster.... how to get the final row.... I tried using $status[0], $status[1] but then the data is not matching

Comment: Ok I did it with array keys

Comment: I'm glad you managed to get it working! Just to answer your question, you can use a for loop to iterate over the array keys in case you used a sequential one, or a foreach loop in case you used the user as the array keys.

Comment: A word of warning concerning the IN statement, as the tables grow, the IN statement can also grow to be so large that just the query transfer and parsing starts taking up the majority of the time. Something a query planner won't tell you.

Comment: @firelynx You are right I have read that IN() comes at its own sql cost. Is there a better alternative to use IN() in my case. All my trouble would have been saved anyways... if oci could handle merging fetches from diff. connection strings.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not meant for this kind of operation, neither should you try to write your own join function.

One proper way of solving this issue is to dump the data from both databases into a local database, and there do the join.
You do not need anything fancy for the local database, an SQLite3 is probably enough.

Just dump the data from each database into a CSV files using a bash script that you put into cron. After the dump, (re)create each table in your SQLite3, and load the CSVs into these tables. After this you can do a join once and push the result into a new table which you then are free to query.

This is what in the datawarehouse world is often referred to as an ETL process, just in this case, very very simplified.

Comment: I apologize, but PHP is meant for this kind of operation, as any other programming language is. I already lost count of how many times I had to connect to several databases and use the data from one of them to filter the data from another.

Comment: PHP was meant to do some preprocessing before you load a HTML page. What it has bloated into is completely irrelevant. I have lost count of how many times I have had to rewrite someones PHP hack into a proper solution, because it was simply not sustainable.

Comment: Also, data warehouses, ETL and similar terms are associated with BI, which does not appear to be the case here at all, it's just some sort of bug tracking / task management software.

Comment: Well, if connecting to a database and fetching some results is not a "preprocessing before you load a HTML page", I don't know what is ;)

Comment: I have a different approach than you. I wrote it before I read your solution. Please do not take offense.

Comment: I didn't. It's just that in an enterprise environment you're almost always stuck with a set of technologies and have to find a way to make things work with what you have.

Comment: Enterprise environments or startup environments, both have CTOs who kling to the only technology they know out of fear of loosing face. However, nothing like that was mentioned in the original question, therefore my answer is valid and in my experience, the better one.